# How to derive a force expression for dipole-dipole interaction

Tags: forces, vector-fields, dipole

## Background

I recently [asked a question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/473355/how-to-cast-dipole-point-charge-force-expression-from-cylindrical-to-cartesian-c) about how to derive a force expression between a point charge and a dipole. This got me wondering whether I could extend this solution to dipole-dipole interactions.

My question centers on how to correctly derive a force expression for dipole-dipole interactions.

## Attempt at solution

I started out with the [dipole-dipole potential](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Physical_Properties_of_Matter/Atomic_and_Molecular_Properties/Intermolecular_Forces/Specific_Interactions/Dipole-Dipole_Interactions) defined with respect to the angles between each dipole, the intermolecular position vector:

$V\left(r,\theta_{1},\theta_{2},\theta_{12}\right)=-k\frac{\mu_{1}\mu_{2}}{r^{3}}\left[\cos\theta_{12}-3\cos\theta_{1}\cos\theta_{2}\right]$

[image]

I then used the geometric interpretation of the dot product to convert each of these angles into respective dot products:

$\cos\theta_{12}=\vec{e_{1}}\cdot\vec{e_{2}}$, $\cos\theta_{1}=\vec{e_{1}}\cdot\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$, and $\cos\theta_{2}=\vec{e_{2}}\cdot\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$

Where $\vec{e}$ is the unit vector along a dipole with moment $\mu$. I then rewrote the potential using these dot products:

$V\left(r\right)=-k\frac{\mu_{1}\mu_{2}}{r^{3}}\left[\vec{e_{1}}\cdot\vec{e_{2}}-3\left(\vec{e_{1}}\cdot\frac{\vec{r}}{r}\right)\left(\vec{e_{2}}\cdot\frac{\vec{r}}{r}\right)\right]$

I then took the gradient of the field:

$\vec{F}_{dipole-dipole}=-\vec{\nabla}V=k\mu_{1}\mu_{2}\vec{\nabla}\left[\frac{\vec{e_{1}}\cdot\vec{e_{2}}}{r^{3}}-\frac{3}{r^{5}}\left(\vec{e_{1}}\cdot\vec{r}\right)\left(\vec{e_{2}}\cdot\vec{r}\right)\right]$

I then applied the product and chain rules alongside these identities

$\vec{\nabla}\left(\vec{e}\cdot\vec{r}\right)=\vec{e}$, $\vec{\nabla}\left(\vec{e_{1}}\cdot\vec{e_{2}}\right)=0$, and $\vec{\nabla}r=\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$

to calculate the gradient:

$\vec{F}_{dipole-dipole}=-3k\mu_{1}\mu_{2}\left[\frac{\vec{e_{1}}\cdot\vec{e_{2}}}{r^{5}}\vec{r}+\left(-5\frac{\left(\vec{e_{1}}\cdot\vec{r}\right)\left(\vec{e_{2}}\cdot\vec{r}\right)}{r^{7}}\vec{r}+\frac{\left(\vec{e_{1}}\cdot\vec{r}\right)}{r^{5}}\vec{e_{2}}+\frac{\left(\vec{e_{2}}\cdot\vec{r}\right)}{r^{5}}\vec{e_{1}}\right)\right]$

which would then be rewritten to group like terms to yield:

$\vec{F}_{dipole-dipole}=-3\frac{k\mu_{1}\mu_{2}}{r^{5}}\left[\left(\vec{e_{1}}\cdot\vec{r}\right)\vec{e_{2}}+\left(\vec{e_{2}}\cdot\vec{r}\right)\vec{e_{1}}+\left(\vec{e_{1}}\cdot\vec{e_{2}}-5\frac{\left(\vec{e_{1}}\cdot\vec{r}\right)\left(\vec{e_{2}}\cdot\vec{r}\right)}{r^{2}}\right)\vec{r}\right]$

Does this derivation of the translational force look reasonable? I haven't attempted the torque expression yet, so any guidance on that is appreciated.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/426091/197851

Comment: @LonelyProf Thank you for pointing towards this. Happy to see that I got the same translational force as your solution. I'll be applying the dipole-dipole torque to my simulations in short order!

Comment: You may need to take care with the signs. Your potential energy, written in terms of the dot products, has a minus sign in front, which I think shouldn't be there. The angles may be defined in different ways with respect to the vector between the dipoles, but when the formula is written in terms of scalar products, it should be unambiguous. Anyway, it is is worth checking this carefully.

Comment: Good point. I think it's because I defined $\vec{r}$ as r2 - r1, where in your derivation it's defined as r1 - r2. If I factor out the negative term from switching (r2-r1) to -(r1-r2) I get a positive sign.

Comment: Yes, it's vital to be consistent one way or the other in choosing a convention for $\vec{r}$, especially in the force formula. But (sorry to go on about this small point) in the formula for $V$, switching the sign of $\vec{r}$ does not change anything. Your *overall* negative sign $-k$ in that formula looks wrong. For two parallel side-by-side dipoles, $\vec{e}_1\cdot\vec{e}_2=1$, $\vec{e}_1\cdot\vec{r}=\vec{e}_2\cdot\vec{r}=0$, $V$ should be positive. Have a think about the physics, with the dipoles represented as separated charges.