# Confusion in mutual torques between two dipoles, and Newton's Third Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, rotational-dynamics, dipole

We have the following setup of two dipoles, separated by distance $x$ ($x>>$length of dipoles), and let us write dipole moment of horizontal one to be $p_1$ and other be $p_2$ setup:

[image]

Now formula for torque due to electric field on a dipole is $\vec\tau=\vec p\times \vec E$ Now let us write torques on vertical dipole due to horizontal one. The electric field will be broadside one, and horizontal towards right: $$\vec\tau_{2,1}=p_2\frac{2kp_1}{x^3}$$

Similarly for another dipole, the electric field will be equatorial and vertically downwards:
$$\vec\tau_{1,2}=p_1\frac{kp_2}{x^3}$$

Now interesting thing is that both will rotate clockwise, or counterclockwise as per the reference frame. It seems counterintuitive to me because possibly due to Newton's third law, the other dipole must feel the equal and opposite force (or torque) and should be rotating in another sense? Does it seem to be violated here? Am I doing or thinking something wrong? Please here, and thanks for any answers/suggestions.

Comment: In my point of view it'll obey the newton's third law if we look at it a bit thoroughly because the formulae you've used here are derived under some approximative conditions which will obviously result in some flaw, try to take some considerable lengths and then try to calculate the torque on either dipoles I think the 3rd law is still valid and if you find something extraordinary please notify me! Thank you for the question.

Comment: Yes I know they are under approximate conditions. I will try again, but I am not very adept in physics, so I came here.

Comment: By the way I've got a source which can help you to get out of this issue, you can check this out [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/425977/why-torque-and-force-between-two-electric-dipoles-are-not-equal-and-opposite-is)

Comment: @Tejas Thank you very much!

Comment: Isn't the whole torque situation much less mysterious if we calculate the torques about a common point. It's then trivially obvious that the torques on the dipoles are equal and opposite!

Answer (score 0):

The expressions for electric forces you use would apply to a *point charge* placed axially to $p_1$ and broadside-on to $p_2$, not to another dipole. Try deriving both $F_{12}$ and $F_{21}$ by thinking of the the dipoles as a set of two charges instead of a  'dipole' and you'll find that the forces have equal magnitudes. The force on $p_1$ would be vertically downwards, and on $p_2$ it would be vertically upwards.

> It seems counterintuitive to me because possibly due to Newton's third law, the other dipole must feel the equal and opposite force (or torque).

Not necessarily. It really depends on their orientations. In fact, both $p_1$  and $p_2$ experience clockwise torques.

Comment: which case you are talking about in which $p_1$ will experience the torque and $p_2$ won't?

Comment: @TejasDahake Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited it now.

Comment: my pleasure brother/sister, yes both of them will experience the torque in this orientation. Moreover with this I am going to say that it's not necessarily required that they should follow newton's third law W.r.t torque so here you are correct, only in the case if the line of action or the force vectors becomes collinear for either of the dipoles in that condition it won't produce any torque. The most important thing is that it should obey the Rotational invarience......

Comment: I got [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/425977/why-torque-and-force-between-two-electric-dipoles-are-not-equal-and-opposite-is) article which helped me a lot to understand I suggest you to check that out too.